# How do we rename or copy the existing Hbase table in MapR without snapshot?

Tags: hive, hbase, mapr, hbase-shell

I am trying to rename existing HBase table but MapR is not supporting any of the existing solutions that I googled. Example export, snapshot etc. Can someone please post the correct steps to rename the existing HBase table in MapR and take a backup of HBase table.

disable 'tableName'
snapshot 'tableName', 'tableSnapshot'
clone_snapshot 'tableSnapshot', 'newTableName'
delete_snapshot 'tableSnapshot'
drop 'tableName'

For this solution getting below error.
ERROR: snapshot for a MapR is unsupported.

Tried mapr copytable -src  -dst 
For this ERROR: is not a JSON table. This tool only supports JSON tables

Answer (score 0):

You can rename a table using the standard Linux command `mv`.

To take a snapshot, take a snapshot of the volume that the table lives in.